# apply two functions by row condition data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`

```
df <- data.table(
id = c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6),rep(3,6)),
grp = c(rep("x",6),rep("y",6),rep("z",6)),
val1 = 1:18,
val2 = 13:30
    )
```

I want two apply two *different* functions by row condition
for example:

```
cols <- paste0("val",1:2)
df[id == 1,lapply(.SD, function (x) tail(x,2)),.SDcols = cols,by = list(id,grp)]

df[id != 1,lapply(.SD, function (x) tail(x,3)),.SDcols = cols,by = list(id,grp)]
```

I'm quite new to working with `data.table` so there is maybe a more efficient way than carrying out separate calculations then joining the two tables above

Comment: Are you sure your conditions are correct? (id == 1) and (id !=2) both apply when id == 1! So your condition is contradictory and code may result in logical error, unless there is some more processing between the 2 lines of code you have left out.

Comment: Good point, had a typo, now updated. Logic should be apply one function when (id == 1) and another function when (id !=1) . ID is grouping variable so it is preserved. @Uwe soultion achieves this.

Answer (score 1):

*If* the conditions are disjunct, i.e., `id == 1` and `id != 1`, *and* *if* `id` is also one of the grouping variables (in the `by =` clause), two *different* functions can be applied by

```
df[, lapply(.SD, function (x) if (first(id) == 1) tail(x, 2) else tail(x, 3)), 
   .SDcols = cols, by = .(id, grp)]
```

> ```
>    id grp val1 val2
> 1:  1   x    5   17
> 2:  1   x    6   18
> 3:  2   y   10   22
> 4:  2   y   11   23
> 5:  2   y   12   24
> 6:  3   z   16   28
> 7:  3   z   17   29
> 8:  3   z   18   30
> ```

So, subsetting is not by row but by grouping variable and has been moved into the anonymous function definition within `lapply()`. This avoids to `rbind()` the subsets afterwards.

---

For the sake of completeness, in the particular case of the `tail()` function being called with different parameters we can write more concisely

```
df[, lapply(.SD, tail, n = fifelse(first(id) == 1, 2, 3)), 
   .SDcols = cols, by = .(id, grp)]
```

Comment: That was what I was after, I do need to preserve ID as it is needed for later processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
df[.N:1L, ri := rowid(id, grp)]
rbindlist(list(
    df[id == 1L & ri <= 2L],    #for the first, df[id == 1L, tail(.SD, 2L), .(id, grp), .SDcols = cols]
    df[id != 1L & ri <= 3L]     #and for df[id != 2, tail(.SD, 3L), .(id,grp), .SDcols = cols]
))
```

output:

```
   id grp val1 val2 ri
1:  1   x    5   17  2
2:  1   x    6   18  1
3:  2   y   10   22  3
4:  2   y   11   23  2
5:  2   y   12   24  1
6:  3   z   16   28  3
7:  3   z   17   29  2
8:  3   z   18   30  1
```

Would be interested to know the size of your dataset and the speedup.

Comment: This is an option and may be quicker, however results in two separate tables.If there is a way to complete this logic in one call that would be useful..@Uwe solution achieves the desired output in one call

Comment: @e.matt do you mean row bind them? you can use `rbindlist`

Comment: @e.matt now what you were looking for makes sense after you changes from 2L to 1L